# Show that $y-x^2 \notin \langle x(x-1), (x-1)y\rangle$ in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

I am in the middle of an exercise and I am stuck in a final step in which I want to show that $y-x^2 \notin \langle x(x-1), (x-1)y\rangle$ in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. My first thought was that $x-1$ does not divide $y-x^2$, but I have no idea how to prove this properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can formalize this intuition by using that
$$\langle x(x-1),(x-1)y\rangle$$
is the set of polynomials that can be written as
$$x(x-1)P(x,y)+(x-1)yQ(x,y)$$
for some polynomials $P,Q$. However, any such polynomial can be written as
$$(x-1)\big(xP(x,y)+yQ(x,y)\big).$$
Can you finish from here?

Comment: I'm sorry, I understand your method but am still not sure how to conclude

Comment: Use what you noted -- that $x-1$ does not divide $y-x^2$. Why would it have to for it to be part of this ideal?

Answer (score 1):

I will use $(~~~~)$ to denote an ideal.

If $y-x^2$ were in the ideal, then $V(y-x^2) \supset V(x(x-1), (x-1)y)$. However, a point such as $(1,0)$ is in $V(x(x-1), (x-1)y)$ but not in $V(y-x^2)$. This is a contradiction.